# Is Google SEO mobile speed performance ranking per domain or per page?

Tags: seo, google, performance

Google announced that from July 2018 - Mobile speed is a ranking factor.

While I am not sure how exactly this is measured, but google hints that the speed score is taken from the CrUX report.

Google [states](https://www.thinkwithgoogle.com/feature/mobile/):

> the ranking methodology is based on a combination of three metrics as
>   reported across mobile devices by the CrUX Report: First Contentful
>   Paint, DOMContentLoaded and Onload.

The question is, is this score for each entire domain, so if a certain site has known slow pages will this effect the entire domain?

Or each page or path gets its own score?

Either way, A source to the answer would be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Both the whole domain speed and page speed will contribute to rankings. The weight of these will most likely be toward page speed.

The tools that Google have released, such as Lighthouse, as all geared towards measuring your page speed and mobile page speed.

If your entire site has slow pages, this will most likely effect your rankings.